# button click should only change the clicked item but it's changing all the items Angular 4

Tags: angular

[image: Front-end display]
The above picture is my current display. when i click on **edit button** it should only **convert** the paragraph tag to **input field** of the selected row.

But in my case it's changing all the paragraph into input fields, i found some solutions but none of them is working.

[image: Display after edit button click]

```
<div id="lists">
            <table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr  class="row" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  *ngFor= 'let item of list let i = index' [attr.data-index]='i'  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i%2 == '0' ? 'gray' : ''}">
                    <td class='default-field'>
                        <p class='para' *ngIf="showHideP">{{i+1}}. {{item}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit-field" *ngIf="tbox" >
                        <input type="text" class="myCl" [value]="val" >
                        <!-- style='display:inline-block;' -->
                    </td>
                    <td class='btns' >

                    <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn' (click)='hidePara(item,i)' *ngIf="edt">

                    <input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' *ngIf="sbtn" (click)='hidePara1(item,i)'> 
                    <input type='button' value='DELETE' class='delete-btn' (click)='deleterow(i)'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

above code is html code

```
  export class AppComponentComponent implements OnInit 
{
  list: string[];
  val: string;
  search:string;
  showHideP: boolean;
  tbox: boolean;
  sbtn: boolean;
  edt: boolean;

 constructor() { 
    this.list=["Purchase a ring for my beautiful wife","get new GALAXY Note 150","Complete kevin's work ASAP","Buy 2 dozen eggs","Get milk on my way to home"];
   this.showHideP = true;
   this.tbox = false;
   this.sbtn = false;
   this.edt = true;

  }
  selectedIndex = 0;
  ngOnInit()  {

  }
  insert=function(temp)
  {
   if(temp!="")
   {
       this.list.unshift(temp);
       this.search="";     
   }
   else
   {
        alert("Enter something");
   }
 }
  deleterow=function(p)
  {    
     if (p > -1) {
     this.list.splice(p, 1);
   }
  }

   hidePara(item,ii){
   this.val=this.list[ii];
   this.showHideP = !this.showHideP;  //for hiding paragraph
   this.tbox = !this.tbox;  //showing text box
   this.edt=!this.edt;  //hide edt button
   this.sbtn = !this.sbtn;  //display save button

 }

  hidePara1(item,ii){

    this.showHideP = !this.showHideP;  //for hiding paragraph
    this.tbox = !this.tbox;  //showing text box
    this.edt=!this.edt;  //hide edt button
    this.sbtn = !this.sbtn;  //display save button 
  }
```

}

the above code is my component, when i click on **edit button** it shows text fields in paragraph place and save button will display and when i click on **save button** it changes to original condition

[image: After edit button click]

After adding Alexis_ni code it is working fine but it shows like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
<div id="lists">
    <table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr  class="row" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  *ngFor= 'let item of list let i = index' [attr.data-index]='i'  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i%2 == '0' ? 'gray' : ''}">
            <td style="width:300px; max-width:300px !important" class='default-field' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i  ">
                <p class='para' >{{i+1}}. {{item}}</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:300px; max-width:300px !important" class="edit-field" *ngIf="selectedIndex==i   " >
                <input type="text" class="myCl" [value]="val" >
            </td>
            <td class='btns' >

            <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn'  (click)='hidePara(item,i)' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i">

            <input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' *ngIf="selectedIndex==i" (click)='hidePara1(item,i)'> 
            <input type='button' value='DELETE' class='delete-btn' (click)='deleterow(i)'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Typescript:

```
      selectedIndex = -1;
    hidePara(item,ii){
  this.selectedIndex=ii;
   this.val=this.list[ii];
   this.showHideP = !this.showHideP;  //for hiding paragraph
   this.tbox = !this.tbox;  //showing text box
   this.edt=!this.edt;  //hide edt button
   this.sbtn = !this.sbtn;  //display save button

 }

  hidePara1(item,ii){
    this.selectedIndex=-1;
    this.showHideP = !this.showHideP;  //for hiding paragraph
    this.tbox = !this.tbox;  //showing text box
    this.edt=!this.edt;  //hide edt button
    this.sbtn = !this.sbtn;  //display save button 
  }
```

Comment: i have edited my question after adding your code it's working fine but creates some issues

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of extra variables like :

```
this.showHideP = true;
this.tbox = false;
this.sbtn = false;
this.edt = true;
```

You can maintain this by using single array

```
editOn: Array<any>;

hidePara(item,ii){
    this.editOn.indexOf(ii) > -1 ? '' : this.editOn.push(ii);
}

hidePara1(item,ii){
    let index = this.editOn.indexOf(ii);
    this.editOn.splice(index,1);
}
```

Template side :

```
*ngIf="editOn.indexOf(i) === -1"
// OR
*ngIf="editOn.indexOf(i) > -1"
```

---

Here is the working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-save-issue

Comment: your code is working fine, i want to ask you when we click on edit button the default field moves to right. From where the padding is applied from?

Comment: @kappo, that's something related to css, In my demo there is no css , so it wont show as yours.Just implemented the functionality.

Comment: @kappo, will you please accpt and upvote the answer?

Comment: @kappo, that issue was because of extra `td` , I have solve that please check demo link again.

Comment: @kappo, in above code you can only edit one row at a time, but in my code you can edit multiple at same time

Comment: @kappo, that is logical part you should implement it,